# A limit problem: $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\frac{1+\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{4}+\cdots+\frac{1}{2^n} }{1+\frac{1}{3}+\frac{1}{9}+\cdots+\frac{1}{3^n} }$

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, limits

I need help in solving the limit below:

> $$\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{1+\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{4}+\cdots+\frac{1}{2^n} }{1+\frac{1}{3}+\frac{1}{9}+\cdots+\frac{1}{3^n} }$$

What I've done is to simplify the upper part to: $$\frac{2^{n+1}-1}{2^n}$$

Any hints or solutions will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you multiply the top by $2$, you get $2x = 2+x$, whence $x = 2$

Likewise, the bottom multiplied by $3$ gives $3y = 3+y$, gives $y = \frac{3}{2}$.

So you then find $\left(\frac{2}{1.5}\right) = \frac{4}{3}$.

Answer (score 4):

Hint:
$$
\sum_{n=0}^Nq^n=\frac{1-q^{N+1}}{1-q}
$$

Comment: You're welcome!

Answer (score 3):

Here are the steps
$$ \lim\limits_{n\to\infty} \frac{\sum\limits_{k=0}^n \frac{1}{2^k}}{\sum\limits_{k=0}^n \frac{1}{3^k}} = \lim\limits_{n\to\infty} \frac{2-\frac1{2^n}}{\frac12\left(3-\frac1{3^n}\right)}$$
$$= \frac{2-0}{\frac12\left(3-0\right)} = \frac2{\frac32} = \frac43$$
Study [geometric series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_series).

Answer (score 2):

**Hint:** Simplify the denominator to
$$\frac{\frac{1}{3^{n+1}}-1}{\frac{1}{3}-1}=\frac{3^{n+1}-1}{2\cdot 3^n}$$

Comment: Thank you. I was having a bit of trouble with just this; I finished the problem myself immediately after posting this though.. But thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Simplify the denominator in the same way that you simplified the numerator. Then you will have a simple ratio of exponentials.

Comment: I know. I didn't know how to do that, that instant. Other answers gave me the hint I realized soon after having posted this question.